# Excel not happily displaying large 2D Range FormulaArray

Tags: c#, c++, excel

I have an XLL which returns an LPXLOPER result of type 2D array for a Range with FormulaArray.

Things go happily <1s update until I hit about size 50x200.  At that point, Excel gets stuck blinking "Ready (pretty Excel graphic)" and "Filling cells (empty progress bar)" at 100% usage of 1 core which goes on for less than half a minute before returning values.

At 100x100 it takes 8-10 minutes.

At 200x100 I'm still waiting for it to return.

The code is identical in all cases.  I step through the VB and it hangs on calling RUN(...) to populate the data array. No further code is executed.  I put breakpoints in my XLL and it doesn't hit any of them. I break into Excel and it's doing Excel stuff in EXCEL.EXE or in libraries I didn't even know existed.

Anyone know (a) what Excel is doing when it says Ready / Filling Cells even though it is obviously NOT ready, and (b) why the nonlinear growth wrt data size?

Comment: Sounds like a question you want to ask Microsoft, *not* StackOverflow.

Comment: One thing I know, is that VBA arrays are really quick.  If you can do all your data within things like [dim DataSet(1 to 200, 1 to 200) ] then I believe you will get your answer faster.  Just allow time to verify that your code to get the data in / out of VBA is doing what you think it's doing, and doesn't result in improperly transposed or cropped tables.

Comment: I don't know at all how C# is involved with this... I'm talking about Excel's native VBA programming interface.

Comment: I am debugging our software package which includes a VBA XLA, an MSVC++ XLL, and an MSVC# component for automatic creation of Excel spreadsheet reports.

Answer (score 0):

I tested an XLL returning a 200x100 array and its virtually instantaneous. So the problem must be either dependency building or calculation or erasing/buildng the cell table.

Try 
- switching calculation to manual to turn off calculation
- setting forcefullcalculation to true to switch off dependency building
- test with an empty workbook to see if it is caused by the workbook contents

Comment: Hello.  I tried swiching Excel to Manual and then hitting UPDATE to execute the formula but it didn't help.
I'll try the forcefullcalculation thingy.
The workbook is entirely empty apart from this one FormulaArray so it's not caused by anything else.

Comment: Hello again.  Forcefullcalculation doesn't help either.

Comment: Could you explain more what you are doing? Why are you using FormulaArray if you are executing the XLL using Application.Run?